# Jade:how can I put render data into context variable

Tags: variables, pug

Suppose I pass `{ "data": "hello" }` into jade template,

then I want give the `data` to a variable like

```
- var temp = #{data}
```

but it failed, What should I do is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve it, the correct solution is

```
- var temp = data
```